# HDMI not connecting (18.04 LTS)

Tags: intel-graphics, hdmi, 18.04, external-monitor

I have just upgraded to 18.04, and all of a sudden my HDMI is not connecting.

> xrandr

```
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1366 x 768, maximum 8192 x 8192
eDP-1 connected primary 1366x768+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y       axis) 344mm x 194mm
   1366x768      60.00*+
   ...
   ...
   320x240       60.05  
   360x202       59.51    59.13  
   320x180       59.84    59.32  
DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

> lspci | grep VGA

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation HD Graphics 510 (rev 07)
```

Everything was working fine, before the upgrade. And I have no idea on where to start debugging. Anyone else has similar problem or an insight on how to fix it??

Comment: What's in your /etc/X11/xorg.conf ? In my case the do-release-update had commented-out 1 line making laptop display black...

Comment: For some reason, it fixed it selfs after an arbitrary amount of boots.

Comment: "Heavy-hand is always the best way to resolve issues" @SteffenHvid

Comment: **Voting to close** - Problem went away on it's own as per comments from OP.

Answer (score 1):

possible solution

1. boot into earlier kernel (4.13 in my case). couldnt login due to unknown issues.
2. reboot into the latest kernel (4.15, installed by 18.04). hdmi detected :)

background:
I migrated from 17.10->18.04 (kubuntu). on installation completion restart, booting to kernel (4.15), hdmi is not detected (xrandr shows hdmi-1-1 disconnected) .
searched around, didnt find any solution (laptop is dell 3450 latitude, nvidia geforce 830M graphics card, intel onboard graphics card)

Comment: I went through the exact same process. Luckely i didn't get to booting into old kernels

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
xrandr --addmode HDMI-1 1366x768
xrandr --output HDMI-1 --mode 1366x768 --right-of eDP-1
```

I have the same issue and in my research I've found this potential temporary solution (the above commands need to be re-run after reboot), but in my case it fails with:

```
xrandr: Configure crtc 1 failed
```

But it might work for you.

Comment: Thanks tried this before it fixed itself, got only errors.

Answer (score 0):

VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation HD Graphics 620 (rev 02)

This all started working for me after I installed recent updates.  I am not exactly sure when this happened, but my HDMI issues are fixed for the above graphics hardware on Ubuntu 18.04.

Answer (score 0):

I had a strange problem with a monitor.
Plugged in HDMI into notebook (thinkpad l580 with ubuntu 18.04 mate) - it was not recognized by xrandr (shown as disconnected).

Plugged in HDMI into another monitor while still plugged into the notebook. After plugging in inlet connector into the monitor it worked.

So I pulled all cables from the first monitor, plugged in HDMI from notebook, after that plugged the inlet connector into the monitor ... and it worked correctly